# Problema com Expressão Regular

Tags: php, regex

Tenho essa expressão regular em php que deveria encontrar o padrão no nome de um arquivo. Exemplo: `dge_ANEXO_II_F_TJ[1].pdf`
Mas não consigo fazer funcionar.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
'/[a-z]{3}_ANEXO|Anexo|anexo_[A-Za-z]{1,7}_[A-Z]{1}_[A-Z0-9]{2,5}....pdf/'
```

Answer (score 6):

Basta acrescentar parênteses na busca pelo `anexo`:

```
/[a-z]{3}_(ANEXO|Anexo|anexo)_[A-Za-z]{1,7}_[A-Z]{1}_[A-Z0-9]{2,5}....pdf/
```

Teste no **[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/pY2nW4/1)**.

**Solução mais completa, prevendo os colchetes:**

O usuário [@DiegoFelipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28595) postou nos *comments* uma solução melhorada, que troca os "coringas" (`...`) pelos colchetes (`\[[0-9]{1}\]`)(notar a diferença no final):

```
/[a-z]{3}_(ANEXO|Anexo|anexo)_[A-Za-z]{1,7}_[A-Z]{1}_[A-Z0-9]{2,5}\[[0-9]{1}\].‌​pdf$/
```

Veja o teste no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/SaVF12)**.

#### Edição @Guilherme Lautert

Caso a palavra "anexo" não tenha rigor de maiúsculo, minúsculo:

```
[a-z]{3}_((?i)anexo)_[A-Za-z]{1,7}_[A-Z]{1}_[A-Z0-9]{2,5}...\.pdf
```

Teste no **[RegEx101.](https://regex101.com/r/pY2nW4/2)**

Uma alternativa um pouco mais "short" caso tenha rigor:

```
[a-z]{3}_(ANEXO|(A|a)nexo)_[A-Za-z]{1,7}_[A-Z]{1}_[A-Z0-9]{2,5}...\.pdf
```

Teste no **[RegEx101.](https://regex101.com/r/pY2nW4/3)**